# IHttpActionResult Returning json without serialization?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I have a simple Get method returning json from a file (for test purposes):

```
public IHttpActionResult GetJson()
    var json = "{ }";
    string fn = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/test1.json");
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fn))
        json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fn);
    return Ok<string>(json);
```

However, the IHttpActionResult function "Ok" seems to try serializing the json even though it already is the format in which I want to return it, which makes the response contain break characters like:

```
{\r\n  \"id\": \"\",\r\n  \"name\": null,\r\n  \"time\": null,\r\n}
```

Is there a built in implementation of IHttpActionResult which returns a json string without trying to serialize it?

Comment: change return type to `string` and `return json;`

Comment: Did you ever solve this @Nakata with still returning IHttpActionResult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the easiest solution to this problem is to deserialize the JSON-string to an object first, then return it:

```
var json_obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
return Json(json_obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a `string`, you should be able to simply do:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetJson()
{
     return Json("...");
}
```

After reading about `Ok` it does indicate the following:

> The content value to negotiate and format the entire body.

So even though `File.ReadAllText` doesn't include the carriage return and line break, I assume that it still holds the formatting.  Which would be why the `Ok` result would attempt to serialize the result.

Comment: I tried returning Json("...") as well, with identical results.

Comment: What does `json` show when you hover?  Just the string or the `/r /n`?

Comment: It depends on if I'm using the json or string viewer, however the returned string always contains /r /n.